# How to retrieve log4net log directory from config file with code

Tags: c#, log4net

I have an application in (this case) C#.net Winforms and i want to show the path of the log4net log directory to the user. 
This path must come from the config file.

How do i do that? System.configuration doesn't seem to work

Comment: That'll be complicated because you could have more than one! It depends on the configuration. So you'll have to search it for FileAppenders and get their config info ... I think I had some link about that, I'll get back to you.

Comment: See this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1094297/Editing-Log-NET-configuration-programatically It's about editing the config, but well - if you can edit, you can read ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var file = ((Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository())
         .Root.Appenders.OfType<FileAppender>().FirstOrDefault().File;
```

simple solution for this....